# Uniswap Fork: Able to add liquidity, but not able to swap

Tags: uniswap, interfaces, forks, liquidity-provider

I am forking uniswap and deploying it on Rinkbey TestNet.

I have successfully deployed factory, router, weth contracts.
I have replaced the respective addresses in the uniswap interface code.

I created few new tokens for testing these: [Token1](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xed26cde38238104bcdc5ce4bfc488ce45ca52e64?a=0x23c1f1d5cd74331d17d3952ec81edc6f331f942e) : KO1

Coming to interface (locally hosted), I am able to add liquidity and the interface is interracting with the deployed contracts.

I added liquidity as 5 ETH per 1 KO1.

But when I come to swap, and try to swap, it shows 'Insuffienct liquidity'.

What to do? What I am missing ??

Contracts deployed from address : [0x23c1f1d5cd74331d17d3952ec81edc6f331f942e](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x23c1f1d5cd74331d17d3952ec81edc6f331f942e)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

These amount*Minparameters should typically be set to percentages of the calculated desired price. So, at a 1% tolerance level, if our user sends a transaction with 1 ETH and 200 DAI, amountETHMin should be set to e.g. .99 ETH, and amountTokenMin should be set to 198 DAI. This means that, at worst, liquidity will be added at a rate between 198 DAI/1 ETH and 202.02 DAI/1 ETH (200 DAI/.99 ETH).

Once the price calculations have been made, it's important to ensure that your contract a) controls at least as many tokens/ETH as were passed as amount*Desired parameters, and b) **has granted approval to the router to withdraw this many tokens**.